# Difference between jquery and $

Tags: jquery

I did heavy use of jquery on my php project. But on some page the `$` is not working, so I have to use jquery. For example:

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
start: 3
});
```

Can anybody please tell me what is the difference between $ and jquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

when `.noConflict()` is called, selector like `$('')` is no longer working to ensure compatibility with other framework such as Prototype. at that time `jQuery('')` is used instead.

Reference: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

To better illustrate the idea, here is an example obtained from the reference link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$` is just a variable that is used to alias `jQuery` and it is a varible so anything could be assigned to it.

You can get detailed information related to it from its [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest possible console experiment which isslustrates what has already been told:

```
($ === jQuery); //true
$.noConflict();
($ === jQuery); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$` represents the jQuery Function, and is an alias for `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

these are same except 
$ is ShortForm of Jquery in Jquery

Comment: @XTG, incorrect, in no conflict mode, `$` is not acting as short form of `jQuery`

Comment: this may help http://css-plus.com/2010/03/6-steps-to-take-if-your-jquery-is-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

It's a jquery conflict. You should use a correct jquery plugin to solve this problem. use a latest Jquery plugin and remove the old one from your code.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is an alias of jQuery in old version.

In latest version if you're using this `$` then that function will not execute.

So, no need to change the entire code with jQuery...

before that code, put:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

very simple...

Answer (score -3):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Emp.asmx/getDesignation',
    type:'post',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "{}",
    aync: false,
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation as to how this answers the question? It appears to me to be completely irrelevant