# Extracting checkboxes values and sending it without form post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to exract values from a checkbox group, but somehow it is not working. Here is what I am doing:

From a loop generating checkboxes

```
<input class="group1" type="checkbox" name="catCheck" value="VALUE_I">
```

There is a button inside a form. On clicking that button, a javascript function is called where I want to extract these values. I have tried following methods:

(1).

```
alert($("input[name=catCheck]:checked").map(
 function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
```

(2).

```
 var matches = [];
$(".group1:checked").each(function() {
    matches.push(this.value);
});
```

Please let me know what am I missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean under "do not work"? Option #2 should works.

Comment: ANd you need a closing tag for your input

Comment: Plzz specify what do u mean by not working ..Any error..

Comment: @ kirilloid an alert statement after these statements does not execute

Comment: Look for error in the js console.

Comment: Your code (2) seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/c7KQL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my jQuery plugin. I work on a large project and somehow there is a conflict.

So in this particular page following code is not working

```
var matches = [];
$(".group1:checked").each(function() {
    matches.push(this.value);
});
```

When I replaced $ with jQuery, it worked!

```
   var matches = [];
   jQuery(".group1:checked").each(function() {
        matches.push(this.value);
    });
```

This link has explained it in detail:
[Difference between jquery and $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631558/difference-between-jquery-and)

But can anyone explain how to locate root of this conflict?