# why there is need of having two method $() and jquery()

Tags: jquery

Both the `$()` and `jquery()` have the same functionality(most of the things says that `$()` is shorthand for `jquery()`) as per my knowledge.

So why there is need to have the two methods for doing the same task?And why was there need to have shorthand for `jquery()` as its not too long(no need to press shift + $).

If they are different than in what sense they are?
And which is more effective either `$()` or `jquery()`?

Using `$()`:[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D4LNS/1/)

```
$( "div" );
```

Using `jQuery()`:[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D4LNS/)

```
jQuery( "div" );
```

Comment: there is no difference, if noConfict was not used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631558/difference-between-jquery-and

Comment: then why two different methods r given to do same work?@undefined

Comment: IF $() and jQuery() have same functionality then why there is need of having two methods for doing the same work?

And which method is more effective?

Comment: `jQuery` is the official jQuery object. `$` is a *convenience alias.* But `$` is also popular among other frameworks, so it can be disabled, in which case you use `jQuery` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just a variable that is used to alias `jQuery` and being a variable, anything could be assigned to it. Some scripts use `jQuery` instead of `$` is to prevent conflicts with other libraries such as prototype or different versions of jquery which both also use the `$` variable.

**Read:** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) states:

"In the first formulation listed above,  jQuery() — which can also be written as $() — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements:"

For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript) post

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery alone then there's no difference. The two forms are synonymous.

If you have a second framework that also uses the `$` variable than you might use jQuery.noConflict() to have jQuery release the `$` variable. In this case `$` will refer to your 'other' framework, while jQuery will always refer to the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Only readability at this level. I prefer the `$` alias simply because it's less typing.

You can change the jQuery prefix to what ever you want in order to prevent conflicts between libraries. Although there are [other tools](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for that too.