# jQuery not executing in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery

Here is a link to some simple jQuery code that I am trying to run in jsFiddle but it generates an exception that text is not a function:

```
<div class="animals">
  <div class="cats">
     <div class="lions">
     meow
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery.find(".animals .lions").text("purr");
jQuery.find(".animals").text("kitty");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/khbwqrte/5/

Comment: You are using find the wrong way; just use jQuery(".animals").text("sdfsdf")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the jQuery lib to Resources on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1jcyb0qu/1/
 And use

```
$(".animals .lions").text("purr");
$(".animals").text("kitty");
```

**From @Raptor:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/15631604/7349445

> when .noConflict() is called, selector like $('') is no longer working
>   to ensure compatibility with other framework such as Prototype. at
>   that time jQuery('') is used instead.
>
> Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
>
> To better illustrate the idea, here is an example obtained from the
>   reference link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: I discovered that a minute ago. Why do I have to use "$"? In my actual code, I can use jQuery.find. Why not in jsFiddle?

Comment: $ is an alias for jQuery is just the way you declare it.

Answer (score 2):

`$` is defined as `jQuery` in jQuery Library, So you can either use `$` or `jQuery`. You Can't use `jQuery.find()` , what you can do is `jQuery(document).find()`

```
jQuery(".animals .lions").text("purr");
jQuery(".animals").text("kitty");
```

OR

```
$(".animals .lions").text("purr");
$(".animals").text("kitty");
```

OR

```
jQuery(document).find(".animals .lions").text("purr");
jQuery(document).find(".animals").text("kitty");
```

Comment: But if I type $.find(".animals") - this will execute in Chrome's console in jsFiddle. I believe Chrome uses its own jQuery in the console that is separate from the one used by jsFiddle.

Comment: @AndroidDev    jQuery.find() should also work on crome then